# Django 3.0 , Csrf token for login page , html page displaying just as code instead of rendering as a page

Tags: django, django-views, django-csrf, django-login

I'm a beginner in django, I made my first login page, and added csrf token, but when the login page is run, it doesn't render as a page, instead shows the template code and each time it is refreshed I can see the csrf token changing in the displayed template code.

I'll put the code below:

views.py:

```
from django.template import RequestContext 
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render
#from django.template import context
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
from .models import Book 
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token


def loginpage(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context_dict = {}
    context_dict.update(csrf(request))

    return render(request,'login.html', context_dict, context)
```

template code getting displayed on browser instead of rendered page:

[image: 1]

I've been trying to sort this out for a few days, but there was no use. Would be wonderful if anyone can help me out here.

Comment: How are you trying to run your django project?

Comment: Other pages in the app run alright, I run it in chrome after 'python manage.py runserver' in terminal,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That one was easy I was overcomplicating it, whenever we need to post a form to another url from templates, we just need to add {% csrf_token %} right after the  opening tag, nothing realted to csrf to do in views or anywhere else, works for me.